# TFS Reporting / Query to Show Execution Status

Tags: tfs, test-report

We are using TFS as our Test Management tool. We need to generate reports  for eg Test Specification and Test Execution. Test Specification will be based on the column (State) and Test execution is obtained with the help of column(Outcome). But only State column is available in list of columns whereas Outcome field is not  available in the list of columns. This is due to technical Problem according to developer and is not recommended to bring back the outcome field. Please let me know if there is any other means or any other columns which helps in generating query for test execution results.

Reporting Server is not yet configured. We need to query result based on available columns
Please help us as it is critical for us

Comment: This will not help you in the short term, but for the long-term, you can influence if & when MS offers the ability to query for test results by up-voting the following feature request....
[Allow for query of test case outcome in TFS](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/11501100-allow-for-query-of-the-test-case-s-outcome-in-tfs)

Answer (score 3):

Without the Reporting Server, your only option to get this information is through the TFS API. This is because TFS does not directly associate test results with test cases: instead there is an implicit linkage through a test run with test points.

- The short version is that each test case may be associated with one or more test runs.
- Each test run will have one or more configuration settings.
- Each distinct setting combination (e.g. operating system = Win7, browser = IE11) is a test point.
- The test result is associated to the test point (because a test case might pass with OS = Win7 and browser = Firefox, but fail when OS = Win7 and browser = IE11).

I suggest you push to get Reporting Server configured and operational, because then you will be able to use the views in the reporting server to pull the information much more easily than trying to get to it programmatically via the API.